# How to pass arguments to inner class with same object for Outer and Inner classes in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, inner-classes

The below code works fine where I'm creating objects for Outer and inner classes individually and passing the arguments

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,rollno):
        self.name = name
        self.rollno = rollno
    def show(self):
        print(self.name,self.rollno)
        #self.lap.show()

    class Laptop: #inner class
        def __init__(self,brand,cpu'):
            self.brand = brand
            self.cpu = cpu
        def show(self):
            print(self.brand,self.cpu)
s1 = Student('Ram',21)
lap1 =s1.Laptop('Dell','i3')
lap1.show()
```

> *In the second code, I have created the inner class(Laptop) object inside the Outer(Student) class. In that case, how can we pass the arguments to the inner class?*

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,rollno):
        self.name = name
        self.rollno = rollno
        self.lap = self.Laptop()  #lap is the obj of a inner class

    def show(self):
        print(self.name,self.rollno)
        self.lap.show()
```

> I tried with self.lap = self.Laptop(brand,cpu), assigning parameters and passing the arguments in differnet ways, but none worked for me.  Is there any way where I can pass the arguments?

Comment: This sounds kind of like you're expecting Java behavior. Defining a class inside another class in Python is mostly just awkward. It doesn't do the stuff that Java inner classes do.

Comment: If you want the `Student` initialiser to create a `Laptop` object then you need to give it the values to pass to the `Laptop` initialiser. For example, you could define it as `__init__(self, name, rollno, brand, cpu)` and pass the latter two when creating the `Laptop`. My preference would be to create the laptop object in the calling code and pass that to the student object, but it depends on how you're going to use it.

Comment: In this case.. how about separate two class?

you can make laptop instance from Laptop class and set laptop attribute in Student instance using laptop instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **really** want Laptop class to be contained in Student class, either pass arguments to Student constructor or replace `self.lap = self.Laptop()` with `self.lap = None`. That way you don't need to worry about those arguments at the time of creating student and can later assign the Laptop to the Student like in the first example.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,rollno):
        self.name = name
        self.rollno = rollno
        self.lap = None  #lap is the obj of a inner class

    def show(self):
        print(self.name,self.rollno)
        self.lap.show() 

    class Laptop: #inner class
        def __init__(self,brand,cpu):
            self.brand = brand
            self.cpu = cpu
        def show(self):
            print(self.brand,self.cpu)

s1 = Student('Ram',21)
lap1 =s1.Laptop('Dell','i3')
lap1.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't really see the added benefit of the inner class. I've seen few usecases where they actually contribute to the readability of the code. In your code I would suggest to simply use two 'top level' classes. Only in some complex cases do inner classes really help.

```py
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, rollno, laptop=None):
        self.name = name
        self.rollno = rollno
        self.laptop = laptop

    def show(self):
        print(self.name, self.rollno)
        if self.laptop:
            self.laptop.show()

class Laptop:
    def __init__(self, brand, cpu):
        self.brand = brand
        self.cpu = cpu

    def show(self):
        print(self.brand, self.cpu)
```

And then in usage, simply initialize and pass them on as needed:

```py
lap1 = Laptop('Dell', 'i3')
s1 = Student('Ram', 21, lap1)
lap1.show()
s1.show()
s2 = Student('Stackoverflow', 9999, lap1)
s2.show()
s3 = Student('No laptop', 2)
s3.show()
```